# Shrink the entire beamer pdf by leaving a 1/2 inch margin on all four edges of each slide, would like to print each slide without notes

Tags: beamer, printing

How do you shrink everything in a beamer such that it leaves 1/2 inch border around each slide? I would like to maximize its size and be able to print everything on each page, including the border.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\begin{document}
\title{Beamer Class well nice}  
\author{Author's name here}
\date{\today} 

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Section no. 2} 
\subsection{Lists I}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{unnumbered lists}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}



\subsection{Lists II}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{numbered lists}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

EDIT: I kept googling and have found what I've been looking for. Modify the lines below to shrink your pdf file. If someone posts this as an answer, I will accept.

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
```

Comment: Post the answer yourself...

Comment: @karlkoeller since I'm a new user, it won't let me post answers.

Comment: I think you can after a certain time or when you get a little reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit these lines into your tex file and it will shrink your pdf document appropriately.

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
```